# SSRS Report on iPAD stuck on Loading - Oracle Data Source

Tags: ios, oracle, ipad, reporting-services, safari

I have a created a number of reports in SSRS using an Oracle Data Source.

These reports run fine on Internet Explorer via Report Manager, but when trying to view these on an iPAD they are stuck at the loading screen and fail to render

The reports can't be cached/viewed from a database snapshot as they query on real time data

Some of the other reports that I have created in SSRS using a SQL Server data source connection run fine on the iPAD. The reports are of the similar style to ones created with the Oracle data source and don’t used cached versions or read data from a database snapshot

The iPAD doesn’t use in-private browsing

Any assistance would be much appreciated as to why this is happening

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of SSRS/Oracle are you using? (Asked for @Brett-C)

Answer (score 0):

Download the Chrome app from the app store. Use Chrome instead of ios webkit to load the SSRS report.  This is a solution that I have implemented.

Comment: t991 -- In order to answer the question of _why_ your SSRS report does not render on iPAD I would need to uncover more information.  Specifically, what version of SSRS/Oracle are you using?